# Calculate mean of values based on matching strings in R

Tags: r, aggregate

Say I have a dataframe `df`:

```
c1   c2
A    1
A    3
A    1
A    3
B    3
B    3
B    3
```

I want to use this dataframe to generate a table that shows each unique value from `c1` and the mean of its corresponding values from `c2`, resulting in this:

```
v1   v2
A    2
B    3
```

because the mean of A's values is 2 ((1+1+3+3)/4) and B's is 3 ((3+3+3)/3).

I'm guessing I need to use aggregate but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
aggregate(c2 ~ c1, df1, mean)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it so the output includes rows for which there are no values? Right now if the average is 0 there is no output.

Comment: @soosus  I am not getting your issue.  Are you saying that there are missing values